# Easy apply option for all jobs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'd like to request for this again. I'm aware that many job listings on StackOverflow jobs are syndicated. I know it may be difficult to implement what I'm suggesting. However, I'd still like to request it since it will benefit the job seeker, the company and StackOverflow.

When applying for jobs, it takes hundreds of applications and a couple of years until some applications turn into interview calls or a job. It is extremely cumbersome to go through this process, especially when companies expect candidates to register on their website and fill in long forms. Companies can actually miss out on good candidates because of this cumbersome process.

If now or in the near future y'all could find a way to allow the "Easy apply" option for all job applications, it'll be a big help. I've requested for the same feature on LinkedIn and Indeed too.